# How do I setup an AWS REST API Gateway (v1) to route to microservices hosted using ECS/Fargate using path based routing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-fargate, amazon-elb

I'm running an API Gateway (v1, we can't use V2/HTTP as we need api usage keys and plans) which currently routes to a bunch (20) microservices running on Elastic Beanstalk. For a variety of reasons including the cost of each application load balancer needed in the Elastic Beanstalk setup (one per microservice), we are planning to migrate to Fargate.

There seems to be no simple way to connect API Gateway to an Application Load Balancer where the path based routing for all microservices could then be done. The closest I've found is this article (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/using-static-ip-addresses-for-application-load-balancers/) . It doesn't seem ideal though as there must be potential for a short amount of downtime when the ALB IP address changes and the lambda hasn't run yet.

The article also mentions Global Accelerator to give the ALB a static IP address, but I believe this only assigns a static **public** IP address, and my ALB will be private.

Comment: I think what you want to do is implement API gateway proxy to an http endpoint no? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-http.html

Comment: Unfortunately not, as APIG is public and we want to connect to resources in our VPC...

Comment: Yes the api gateway would connect to your http back end on fargate via its loadbalancer. On your vpc. Isn't that what you want to do? That is what the proxy does. I'm sure this pattern is doable snd somewhat common.

Comment: Fargate doesn't have a load balancer though - that's the part that needs figuring out. APIG V1 can only connect to a Network Load Balancer (NLB) via a VPC Link, so I'm thinking to have one NLB which listens on a variety of ports (a different one per microservice), APIG would know which port to send which requests to (ie based on api/path); fargate would register microservice containers to the appropriate listener. An ALB would be better as it can do path based routing... I'll update with where I get to.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-load-balancing.html ELB does support ECS Fargate just fyi

Answer (score 0):

I think what you'll need to do is set-up routes that send traffic to specific ports where your containers are listening. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-advanced-request-routing-for-aws-application-load-balancers/